# How to work angular2-indexeddb?

Tags: angularjs, angular, indexeddb

I have learn angular2-indexeddb service. But, not understand some point to indexeddb.

1. What is indexeddb?
2. How to store data?
3. Support all browser for this service?
4. How to work this service?

Please explain more details of this service.

Answer (score 5):

**1. What is indexedDB?**

**ANS:** The indexeddb is a new HTML5 concept to store the data inside user's browser. indexeddb is more power than local storage and useful for applications that requires to store large amount of the data. These applications can run more efficiency and load faster.

**2. How to store data?**

**ANS:** Store data in your web browser using IndexedDB API

**3. Support all browser for this service?**

**ANS:** Some older browsers don't support IndexedDB but do support WebSQL. One way around this problem is to use an IndexedDB Polyfill or Shim that falls back to WebSQL or even localStorage for non-supporting browsers. The best available polyfill at present is localForage.

**4. How to work this service?**

**ANS:** Please check this Url [click here](https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb)

**More Resources:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API
http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/01/14/html5-learn-how-to-use-indexeddb/

Comment: Nice job, clean and objective.